# PHP Connection: Close

Tags: php, http-headers, connection

I have a PHP application that I have been having some problems with, some pages take a very long time to load.

After a couple of hours I have figured out the problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.

The problem seems to be with the header `Connection: keep-alive`. I used a Firefox plugin called "Tamper Data" which allows you to "tamper" with the headers and stuff. Once I used that tool to change the connection header to `Connection: close` the delay on some pages stopped.

How, in PHP, can I make sure that the `Connection: close` header is used?

I tried putting `header("Connection: close");` at the top of a PHP file, and reloaded the page. It still sends the `Connection: keep-alive` header, not the one I am trying to send.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

**EDIT:** I have just realized that on this subdomain the content-length header is not sent at all for most pages. It is only sent right after a form submission followed by a redirect.

**EDIT 2:**

This is the page: http://volunteer.essentialtransit.com/job/13/just-a-test-at-eta/

Click the "Apply now" link and fill out some random txt, you don't need to attach a file. Notice when you are redirected back to the "job" detail page that it will take a very long time to load.

Comment: What server are you using?  This shouldn't have anything to do with PHP, except in rare circumstances.

Comment: Apache. However, I'm on shared hosting, so cannot modify the Apache config files.

Comment: Make sure to use backticks (`) around inline code instead of single or double quotes.

Comment: And if you can send headers in PHP wouldn't I be able to send the "connection" header as well?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the backticks :)

Comment: You're not just sending a header, you're trying to control the behavior of the server.  That's why you can't control keep-alive from PHP.  In any case, you should try to fix the actual problem rather than disabling this.  It is a very useful feature.  I suspect if disabling keep-alive is "fixing" your problem, then your hosting provider should look into what the issue is.  If you could post a URL, I can dig a bit from here.

Comment: This problem only occurs on one subdomain on the site, with the main site, and several other subdomains working properly. I'm not sure why in this case this problem is happening. I did notice that on the pages I'm having a problem with the content-length header is also set, but set at 0. On other pages of my site this has an actual value.

Comment: Actually, on other pages the content-length is either set at a numerical value, or that header is not sent at all.

Comment: So, I don;t think it is a server config issue, because all other areas of the site work fine with `Connection: keep-alive` by either specifying a value, or not sending the header.

Comment: Also, the pages that are slow to load are ones that are redirected to after submitting a form. So form is submitted, then redirect happens, then page is slow to load. However, the same page loads normally when loaded directly, without the form and redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I determined what the problem was, and found a work-around to this issue.

The script that processed the form just processed the input and redirected to another page, but it actually didn't output anything. On most pages on the site the content-length header is either not sent, or is set at the correct value. But for some reason when posting to a page, and then redirecting without the processing script outputting anything to the browser, the content-length was being set at 0.

I tried setting the content-length myself, but didn't have much luck, as it didn't seem to make a difference.

So, all I did was make the processing script have some output. So now when the form is submitted the processing script outputs a page with a redirect script (and a 'click to continue' message just in case) that leads to the correct page. So while this adds a very brief delay between the form submission and the correct page being seen it causes the content-length to be set correctly and the problem is solved.

While this is not an ideal solution it is manageable and makes the script work.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with connection states. It might seem related to connections because Apache automatically spawns a new child thread for each new request originating from a different source. With keep-alive, it will attempt to reuse the previous thread, which is busy from a PHP script (from your application). It's a little more complicated actually but this is the basic. Just note that "Connection: Close" is being sent, but it's supposed to close the connection only after the script has finished (sent all buffers out).

Now I'm going to tell you how to debug your script. I'll do this because if you don't fix your problem and you gain more traffic, your host will kick you out for extreme resource usage.

So:

1. Append `set_time_limit(5)` or higher to confirm there's a background script problem
2. Check for requests to local resources, requests that would only work on your staging server (you can use WireShark for this)
3. Check for external requests, cURL, `file_get_contents()` calls, anything with a timeout
4. Benchmark and optimize lengthy scripts (you can try xdebug for this)
5. Log all PHP notices, warnings and errors to a file; you should get at most zero errors
6. Finally, it's a good practice to triple-check your entire application. One for data entry, second for data operations and third for modules interconnection. But you should focus on AJAX background scripts that can't return output

Of course, skip anything that doesn't apply.

Comment: Before I try the ones that MAY apply, I wanted to make sure I explained things right. The page loads fine when the address is typed in, or when you follow a link to it. The problem only occurs after the form on the page is submitted and then the user is redirected back to the page. The page contains details of volunteer opportunities and has an application form. That form is submitted to the processing script, and then the processing script redirects you back to the same page you were on.

Comment: In both cases the script is accessed in the exact same way, the only difference I could find was the content-length header is included, and set at 0, after the redirect. 

The only thing that is different is that there is a session variable set that says the person submitted an application, which allows a "success" message to be shown. If this were caused by a background script wouldn't the same problem occur when the same page was accessed directly?

Comment: This is the page: http://volunteer.essentialtransit.com/job/13/just-a-test-at-eta/

Click the "Apply now" link and fill out some random txt, you don't need to attach a file. Notice when you are redirected back to the "job" detail page that it will take a very long time to load.

Comment: @SherwinFlight You're in an endless redirection loop. Here's the page with problems, open it with Chrome: http://volunteer.essentialtransit.com/apply-online/ The page attempts to set session, but it fails because it has to output warnings.

Comment: That page is not meant to be accessed directly. So, I added a referrer check, and will redirect when the page is directly accessed. I have errors enabled right now to debug, but will turn them off after.